# Applescript - Check if list of URL's contains any of these words from list

Tags: web-scraping, applescript

I have two lists. List A contains URL's and List B contains Words. I need to return every URL that contains any of the words (Filtering).

I have managed to check if true/false but not to return the URL's containing any of the words.

```
set theURLs to {"www.audi.com", "www.vw.com", "www.suzuki.com"} as text
set KeywordFilter to {"dodge", "audi", "chevy"}
set doesContain to containsItems from KeywordFilter against theURLs


on containsItems from qList against theText
    set pageURLs to {}
    repeat with anItem in qList
        if theText contains anItem then return true
    end repeat
    return false
end containsItems
```

Do i need another loop to return the matching URL's in a String?

Thanks everyone for the kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coercing a list to text

```
set theURLs to {"www.audi.com", "www.vw.com", "www.suzuki.com"} as text
```

is a bad idea, the result is – depending on `text item delimiters` – `"www.audi.comwww.vw.comwww.suzuki.com"`

---

To compare *two* lists you need *two* loops

```
set theURLs to {"www.audi.com", "www.vw.com", "www.suzuki.com"}
set KeywordFilter to {"dodge", "audi", "chevy"}
set foundURLs to containsItems from KeywordFilter against theURLs

on containsItems from qList against theText
    set pageURLs to {}
    repeat with aText in theText
        repeat with anItem in qList
            if aText contains anItem then set end of pageURLs to contents of anItem
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return pageURLs
end containsItems
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just needed to change the line: `if aText contains anItem then set end of pageURLs to contents of anItem` to `if aText contains anItem then set end of pageURLs to contents of aText `as i need to return the URL and not the filter/keyword. Liebe Grüsse aus Zürich

Comment: as the value of pageURLs is not available outside the containsItems action, how would i replace the ON and END to stay in the same workflow? Thank you

Comment: `foundURLs` represents the result of `pageURLs` on return. To get rid of the entire handler remove the `on ...`, `return...` and `end...` lines and replace the occurrences of `qList` in the handler with `KeywordFilter` and `theText` with `theURLs`.